# Excel chart grid size and multiple colors (no VBA)

Tags: excel, charts

I would like to ask for your help on two major problems I have with an Excel (2003) chart:

1) I would like to create a chart which has got 25 grids (5 on the x axis and 5 on the y axis). The number of grids must not change, i.e. data should have no impact on the size, length and number of grids (several different worksheets are used as input to the chart). How can I create such a chart without having different grid lenghts depending on data?

2) I need a chart which has 25 grids, with each grid being colored differently, e.g. for example 3 grids in the upper right corner are red, 3 grids in lower left corner are green, inbetween all grids are colored white. I have read some articles on creating charts with a quadrant background, i.e. 4 grids, each having a different color. But I would like to know how I can create multi colored background for 25 grids?

Many thanks in advance!!

Regards,

Comment: You can use the link below to create bands. From there it should be a small amount of effort to create a grid from that. http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-charts-with-horizontal-bands/

Comment: user1855071, did you find useful anything posted here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use VBA, there are a number of hand steps that are needed to create the grid chart you are looking for.  For the most part, these steps can be taken in any order.

- Enter what will be the horizontal column labels in a 1 x 5 cell range in your worksheet.
- In the 5 x 5 cell range immediately below, enter the value 1 in each cell.
- Selecting the 6 x 5 cell range, insert a 100% Stacked Column chart into the worksheet. You will now have a chart with of bars with five horizontal bands, each of a different color.
- Delete the legend.
- Select one of the bands to format and set its Gap Width to "No Gap."
- Insert a chart title and horizontal and vertical axis titles, if any.
- Select each band (data series) and set its fill color to solid fill white and its border color to solid line black.
- Select the chart area and set its height and width to identical values.
- Lock the chart area's aspect ratio.
- Select and set the fill color of each data point (grid cell) that you want in a contrasting color.

(I am unaware of any way to dynamically set the colors of the grid cells based upon different data values, other than via VBA.)

- If you want to change the font size of the labels of one of the axes, be sure to set the other axis to the same size to preserve the square grid layout.
- Set the major tick mark type of the vertical axis to None, and the font color of the vertical axis labels to white.
- At this point, you may want to shift the plot area to the left so that there is more white space between the right borders of the plot area and the chart area.
- Select the chart area and then insert a text box over the vertical axis label area.
- Enter into the text box the vertical axis labels that you want to show, with a blank line between each label, and with the font size and color of your choice.
- Move the text box vertically so that, by eye, the first of labels in the text box is by eye aligned vertically with the center of  the top row of the grid.
- Select the blank line between the first two labels in the text box and change the line's font size so that, again by eye, the second label is aligned vertically with the center of the second grid row. Continue with the three remaining labels.
- If you want finer control of the alignment of the labels, insert a second line between the each pair of labels and set the font size for the second lines in a smaller font than the first lines.
- This text box is the only element of the chart that will not automatically resize if you change the size of the chart.

Other than any minor tweaking of the font sizes or alignment of the chart title and the axis labels, the chart is done:

[image: The Final Product]